# How can I send an ODBC connection string to an SQL server if the user is authenticated by Active Directory?

Tags: .net, sql-server, active-directory, connection-string

Technologies:SQL Server 2008, .NET 2008, Active Directory

I'm trying to send a connection string via my application to the SQL Server to authenticate a username and password that is stored in Active Directory, not locally on the db server.

Unfortunately, this isn't working because when I send the connection string, it only checks the SQL server local users, instead of checking the credentials against active directory. Does anyone know of a solution?

Currently using ODBC to make the connection.

Comment: Have you enabled Windows authentication mode on SQL Server? Have you created logins and users for your AD users/groups in SQL ServeR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make a connection to SQL Server in this way.   SQL Server supports only two kinds of connections:

1. SQL Login, where to connect, you supply it with the username and password of a *SQL Login* (i.e., *not* a Windows/AD Logon) defined on that SQL Server.  or,
2. A Trusted Connection, where to connect, you supply it with *NO* username or password and it connects you to a session based on your current Windows session's security context (assuming you are so authorized).

Those are your only choices.  If you want to connect to SQL Server as a different Windows/AD security context, you will have to create a *Windows* session with that context first.

Comment: What about running the application as the desired user and using the trusted connection clause?

Comment: That would be the same as "you will have to create a windows session with that context first.", which is what I said.

Comment: Right. Either way, it's a web service running via IIS, and it works now.